# Xamarin.Forms - Is there a quick and easy way to increment the already bound value of Label.Text in XAML only?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm, string-formatting

I need to increment the value of some labels without changing the value of the binding context.

I know I could just create a new variable in my MVVM which is the incremented version of my original value but is there an easy and fast way to do the same thing in XAML only (since I would need to change this projectwide and only need this for frontend)?

Does something like this exist?

```
<Label>
    <Label.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="INCREMENT BINDING BY 1">
            <Binding Path="MyValue">
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Text>
</Label>
```

^Pseudo code which I have in my mind

Comment: You want to bind a label to a property but update the label without updating the property?

Comment: You can do [BindingMode.OneWay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.bindingmode?view=xamarin-forms#xamarin-forms-bindingmode-oneway), then any changes you make to the label in the code behind won't be sent back to the VM. You could do something with a hidden label and toggle the visibility as needed. There's several ways to do what you're looking for. However, something doesn't sound right with your requirement. If you could tell us why you want a data bound label that you want to increment separately from the vm property, we can probably suggest a better way.

Comment: Maybe use an IValueConverter, to alter the incoming value.

Comment: @Andrew The property value represents an index in a list and I've used 0 as starting index throughout the whole project logic. The index is shown in a label in a listview but it would be better if the first element would be shown with index 1. But I don't really want to change the index logic. I will try the one-way binding later

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I will also try this later and will give feedback

Comment: Alternative solutions may be possible, if you **show the code and xaml** you have, explain some details. Show a snippet of xaml and the corresponding property in c#.  Does the xaml contain `propertyname[index]`? Are you indexing into the **same** data on different pages, or are there multiple different lists you need to index? Re "adding a new property". You might be thinking that is more work than it is - it should be as simple as `public int mypropertyplus1 => myproperty + 1;`

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Each object in my list of objects contains an property 'index'. Simply adding another property 'indexPlus1' = 'index' + 1 and then changing the binding context to the new property might really be the most simple solution. I could ignore this property when writing the list to a db.. Thanks I will do it this way - posting this as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to increment the property `myValue` in label.text is to create a new property in MVVM
`myValuePlus1{ get { return myValue + 1; }}` and use `myValuePlus1` as binding source instead of `myValue`.